# SQL query to consolidate names

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, unique, consolidation

Table data has a field 'Name' with data like this

| Names | State |
| --- | --- |
| Sometimes | WA |
| Some times | KS |
| Som etimes | NY |
| ABCDE Corp | CA |
| SSS Corp | WA |
| SSS Corporation | VI |
| ABCDE | CA |
| ABCDE Corporation | NJ |

Need to consolidate names dynamically

| Names | State |
| --- | --- |
| Sometimes | WA |
| Sometimes | KS |
| Sometimes | NY |
| ABCDE Corp | CA |
| SSS Corp | WA |
| SSS Corp | VI |
| ABCDE Corp | CA |
| ABCDE Corp | NJ |

Tried below query but no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1]
WHERE LEFT([Name], 5) IN 
(
        SELECT LEFT([Name], 5)
        FROM [Table1]
        GROUP BY LEFT([Name], 5)
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Any alternate suggestions to derive common name dynamically in SQL Server? Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like what you really need to fix is the input method and have someone then clean up the *bad* data.

Comment: define "common name" first

Comment: Consolidate is the wrong word, this is data cleaning and as such you need to define a set of rules to apply. And typically it's quite hard to get right. Because you need a way to detect that the space shouldn't be there, or that the word should be shortened.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into #temp values (
'Sometimes',    'WA'),
('Some times',  'KS'),
('Som etimes',  'NY'),
('ABCDE Corp',  'CA'),
('SSS Corp',    'WA'),
('SSS Corporation',     'VI'),
('ABCDE',   'CA'),
('ABCDE Corporation',   'NJ')

--#temp is your table1 and the following two lines is all you need to run to get the desired output, just change the table name. 

DECLARE @Whitespace CHAR(4) = CHAR(0) + CHAR(9) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

select Replace(REPLACE(Names, 'e t','et'),'m e','me') Name from #temp



drop table #temp
```

Comment: What is "dynamic" about this?

Comment: @ThomA, the problem is he's trying to solve is to remove whitespace, but he, and it seems you, do not understand that one can't do it without providing adequate information about which whitespace to remove. It's not and cannot be dynamic. The problem requires more information than anything remotely generic can accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Names, ' Corporation', CHAR(7) + 'Corp'), ' ', ''), CHAR(7), ' ') AS NewNames
FROM [Table1]
```

This will replace "Corporation" by "Corp", remove all blank except those before "Corporation".